# Custom attribute two way binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this example I face 2 problems

**https://jsfiddle.net/1g6kvxst/**

1. Obviously `<b>{{moo}}</b>` isn't updated. Isn't the expression `{{moo}}` supposed to be 2 way binding ?
2. And probably because of the first problem my watch expression about directive `my-var` attr value in link callback  isn't updated

What am I missing? Appreciate your kind help.

**View**

`<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div my-directive my-var="moo"></div>
    <span>Result:</span> <b>{{moo}}</b>
</section>`

**Directive**

```
App.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            myVar: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(scope.myVar, function() {          
                console.log('my var changed to: ', scope.myVar);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
var ctrls = angular.module('controllers',[]);
ctrls.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.moo = 0; 
    var t = setInterval(function(){
        $scope.moo++;
    },1000);
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses watches to re-evaluate variables in the view. These watches are build in angular's async functions, like `$timeout`, `$http` etc. When using the native `setTimeout`, angular's digest cycle does not pick up that change;

Use angular's `$interval` service instead of the native javascript interval:

```
var t = $interval(function(){
    $scope.moo++;
},1000);
```

Don't forget to inject into the controller:

```
ctrls.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$interval', function ($scope, $interval) {
```

To make the `$watch` work, watch the key and not the object:

```
scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/deuroquL/1/)

Comment: 10x that worked for the first problem but still my `$watch` expression in the directive isn't updated

Comment: You need to watch `'myVar'` (the key), not `scope.myVar` (the object reference)

Answer (score 2):

use `$interval`, not `setInterval`, angular doesn't run a digest loop when you use `setTimeout`, and thus your directives scope is not aware of any changes.

Comment: You probably mean `$interval` instead of `$timeout`